# qual o procedimento para inserir 1 apenas 1 checkbox value no mysql com php?

Tags: php, mysql

Na pesquisa que tenho feito sobre checkbox tenho visto várias alternativas para inserção de valores de checkbox, usando métodos com array e laços.

Porém desejo inserir apenas 1, ainda é necessário o uso de array e laços.

O código a seguir está retornando erro, como adequar de forma mais simples possível.

```
<form method="post" action="trata_check.php">
  <input id="" type="checkbox" name="um" value="um">Um
  <input id="" type="submit"  value="gogopls">
</form>
```

trata_check.php

```
<?php
include 'conect.php';

$um = $_POST['um'];

$sql = 
"INSERT INTO part_1
(um)
VALUES 
('$um')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "realizado";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$con->close();

?>
```

Não estou achando uma solução .

Comment: preciso do colchetes no input tmb?

Comment: Me equivoquei, não tem array no seu código. Como você está submitando o form?

Comment: <input type"submit" value="gogopls">

Comment: tá recebendo o valor 1, e não a string...

Comment: Que erro que acontece?

Comment: Sem erro mas recebe 1 como valor....

Comment: Não sei como mas agora funfou.... mygood gratz @diegofm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="trata_check.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="um" value="1" id="" <?= (isset($dados['um']) && $dados['um'] == 1) ? 'checked' : '' ?> >Um
  <input id="" type="submit"  value="gogopls">
</form>

<?php
include 'conect.php';

$um = 0;
if(isset($_POST['um']) && !empty($_POST['um'])){
 $um = 1;
}
 $sql = "INSERT INTO part_1 (um) VALUES ('{$um}')";
  if (!$con->query($sql)) {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
  } 
$con->close();
echo "realizado";
```